# reusing business logic in a test class to save time

Tags: unit-testing

Just having a conversation with someone in the office about using a business logic class to build up some data in order to test another class.

Basically, he has class A which takes a complex type as a parameter and then generates a collection of a different complex type as a result.  He's written tests around this class already.  Now he's moved on to testing another class (class B) which takes the result of class A then performs some logic on it.

He's asked the question, "should I use class A to build up a scenario to test class B with".

At first I said yes as class A has tests around it.  But then I figured well what if there's some bugs in class A that we haven't found yet... so I guess there must be a better way to address this scenario.

**Does anyone have any thoughts on this?  Is it OK to use existing logic to save time writing other tests?**

Regards,

James

Comment: I would take the stance that all inputs to a unit test should be predictable and not the output of another method. If that is the case, you cease to be testing a unit of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stances on that might differ. Generally, if code is tested and you *assume it works*, you're free to use it. This is especially true when using [already tested methods to help with testing others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9018501/343266) (within single class/unit). However, as this happens within single unit it's a bit different from your case.

Now, when dealing with 2 separate classes I'd say you should avoid such approach. Purely for the reason that **those two classes might not be related in obvious way** or their context/scope of usage might vastly differ. As in, somebody might change class A without even knowing class B exists. Class B tests suddenly break even though no changes were made to B code. This brings unnecessary confusion and is situation you usually don't want to find yourself in.

Instead, I suggest creating helper method within tested class B file. With stubs/fakes and tools like [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/), you should be able to easily reproduce generation logic used by class A and have your own "copy" contained in class B tests.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test class B, the result returned from the class A should be replicated somewhere in your test. If class A returns a list of persons, you will have an helper function in your test returning a fake `List<Person>` to use for your test. 
Because you are only testing the class B, class A should not be used in your test.

NUnit provides a built in functionality in order to provide data for your tests, have a look to : 
http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5

Or you can simply create a DataFactory class with methods that returns the data (simple objects, collections etc..) you will consume in your tests.