# How can I keep my unit tests independent of each other in this simple case?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I'm writing a small game in C# using Test Driven Development approach. I'm facing a problem:

I have a class `CheckersBoard`:

```
public class CheckersBoard
{
    private const string InitialBoardPattern = "B-B-B-B-" +
                                               "-B-B-B-B" +
                                               "B-B-B-B-" +
                                               "--------" +
                                               "--------" +
                                               "-W-W-W-W" +
                                               "W-W-W-W-" +
                                               "-W-W-W-W";

    public SquareStatus[,] Squares { get; private set; }

    public CheckersBoard(IBoardGenerator boardGenerator)
    {
        Squares = boardGenerator.GenerateFromPattern(InitialBoardPattern, 8, 8);
    }

    //....
}
```

And a class `BoardGenerator`:

```
public class BoardGenerator : IBoardGenerator
{

    public SquareStatus[,] GenerateFromPattern(string pattern, int width, int height)
    {
        //....
    }

}
```

`BoardGenerator` allows me to initialize `CheckersBoard` in a very readable way. So, I really would like to use `BoardGenerator` in my unit tests to avoid ugly array initialization.

But it's against the rule that says that I must keep all my unit tests independent of each other. If the test of `GenerateFromPattern` fails, that will produce a "cascade" effect and all the tests which use `GenerateFromPattern` will fail too.

This is the first time I have ever used unit tests so I'm a little bit confused. How can I avoid this problem? Is there something wrong with my design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a common problem without obvious answer, and I happened to deal with two similar questions:

- [Reusing business logic in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091514/reusing-business-logic-in-a-test-class-to-save-time) - advising **against**, because OP talks about 2 different components (similar to your case)
- [Using tested function to prepare another unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018142/is-it-a-good-way-of-unit-testing-to-use-another-tested-function-to-make-prepara) - advising **for**, given then usage is scoped to single class (so that new bugs won't possibly crash some totally unrelated component, but instead all will remain within original *"crashing scope"*)

To certain level, reusing business logic (other, tested components) is *kind of* similar to using 3rd party libraries in unit testing - we assume they work, and don't bother generating extra assertions about them. Will you have any hesitations to use `List<T>` in unit test? Most likely no. Note however, that `List<T>` is tested by many other developers daily and has big software house behind it. Can you say the same about `BoardGenerator`?

Another question to consider is, will the `CheckersBoard` test code be as obvious to somebody who never worked on `BoardGenerator` as it is to you? You claim it is readable, but that's common given the authoring. Maybe using array initialization is *not as bad* (unreadable) as you think it is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! As I said this is my first project where I'm using unit tests. I'm just trying to familiarize myself with the concept. So, I wanted to make sure I know how to face a similar problem in the future. It seems clarified to me now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) your `BoardGenerator` class or just fake the implementation e.g.

```
internal class MockBoardGenerator : IBoardGenerator
{
    public SquareStatus[,] GenerateFromPattern(string pattern, int width, int height)
    {
        // return fixed test data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm already mocking it. My problem is I want to initialize my game board in my tests in a readable way to keep them easy to understand. So I really want to use a string initialization instead of an array initialization.

Comment: @user1642427 Sorry you hadn't mentioned that you were already mocking your board in your original question. "*I really want to use a string initialization instead of an array initialization*" - Couldn't you have your `BoardGenerator` support the 2 methods and just the string one for testing?

Comment: Yes, I didn't express myself very well. Sorry for that. `GenerateFromPattern` is a sort a helper method to initialize my board elegantly. So I actually need it both in my production project and in my testing project. I need its **real** implementation to make my tests more readable. Maybe a solution could be to clone it in my testing project. I'll have a sort of BoardHelper static class wich will do the same job in my testing project. But's it sounds a little bit ugly to me...

Comment: Sounds like you would want to use the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for this. That way you can have a separate `TestBoardGenerator` class which overrides the behaviour of `GenerateFromPattern`.

Comment: That's a misunderstanding. I don't want to override anything of `TestBoardGenerator`. I want to use the default implementation of `GenerateFromPattern` method as it in my unit tests. So the question was : "Can I use this method in another unit test and assumes it works?". jimmy_keen's anwer is very informative about this problem. Thank you for your help @James !