# Static class/method/property in unit test, stop it or not

Tags: c#, java, unit-testing, tdd

Should a static class/method/property be used in a unit test development environment, given that there is no way to test it without introducing a wrapper that is again not testable?

Another scenario is that when the static members are used within the unit tested target, the static member cannot be mocked. Thus, you have to test the static members when the unit tested target is tested. You want to isolate it when the static member performs calculation.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Testing static method is no different than testing any other method. Having static method as a *dependency* inside another tested module raises problems (as it's been mentioned - you can't mock/stub it with free tools). But if the static method itself is unit tested you can simply [treat it as working, reliable component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9018501/343266).

Overall, there's nothing wrong (as in, it doesn't disrupt unit testing/TDD) with static methods when:

- it is simple, input-output method (all kinds of *"calculate this given that"*)
- it is *reliable*, by what we mean it's either unit tested by you or comes from 3rd party source you consider reliable (eg. `Math.Floor` might be considered reliable - using it shouldn't raise *"Look out, it's static!"* warning; one might assume Microsoft does its job)

When static methods will cause problems and should be avoided? Basically only when they interact with/**do something you cannot control** (or mock):

- all kind of file system, database, network dependencies
- other (possibly more complex) static methods called from inside
- pretty much anything your mocking framework can't deal with on regular terms

**Edit:** *two examples on when static method **will** make unit testing hard*

**1**

```
public int ExtractSumFromReport(string reportPath)
{
     var reportFile = File.ReadAllText(reportPath);
     // ...
}
```

How do you deal with `File.ReadAllText`? This will obviously go to file system to retrieve file content, which is major no-no when unit testing. This is example of static method with external dependency. To avoid that, you usually create wrapper around file system api or simply inject it as dependency/delegate.

**2**

```
public void SaveUser(User user)
{
    var session = SessionFactory.CreateSession();
    // ...
}
```

What about this? Session is *non-trivial* dependency. Sure, it might come as `ISession`, but how do force `SessionFactory` to return mock? We can't. And we can't create *easy to detemine* session object either.

In cases like above, it's best to avoid static methods altogether.

Comment: what about when the static method performs calculation, and you cannot mock it? Does it require to make it instance method?

Comment: @Pingpong: Could you expand a bit? `Math.Floor` performs calculations - do we mock it? No, because we know `Math.Floor(2.5)` will return 2. When input-output is **easy to determine** you don't have to mock anything (or use instance). The whole *static method makes testing hard* comes from situations when they provide non-trivial dependencies or have side effects. See my edit.

Comment: What about the static method is a custom method that performs long process calcuation?

Comment: @Pingpong: unit tests should execute fast. If something is slowing them, it most likely should be abstracted. Or simply do an integration test instead (tho in most cases you will need both).

Comment: Good examples (1,2). If we only use instance members when possible, why we need both?

Comment: I like this type of approaches more than simply do not do this approaches. There are cases when static methods are good options and if you are a careful developer, you will always keep Implications of your choices in mind when writing code. Otherwise, even a simple thing can be deadly in the hands of careless novice developer.

Comment: I think this is the best answer! The emphasis should be this: `if the static method itself is unit tested you can simply treat it as working, reliable component`. So this means you don't need to mock it, just let the code under test call it as it is. However, this means you'll have to prepare potentially more data in your test..

Answer (score 3):

Static methods **CAN** be unit tested. They can't be mocked (generally; there are some frameworks to do this like [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/).

Comment: But this is overkill for simple cases. Moles integrates in build process and available only for .net

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock static methods/properties. So, when your `classA` uses some static member of `classB` you can't test `classA` in isolation.

UPDATE: I don't see any problem of wrapping some static class into object. It doesn't take lot of time, but it allows you to decrease coupling in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you **can** mock the static method in Java with [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/), but if you need to do this I would seriously recommend to refactor your code. I think that static methods should always be `private` and used only inside the classes they are defined in, for internal purposes. I consider publicly exposed static method as [a code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Answer (score 0):

I find this threat regardless of the programming language, but since my daily life is related to PHP, here is good resource to deal with static methods on PHP http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_static_properties.html