# How do I run unit tests in VS based on different values of a static variable?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am trying to write a unit test to make sure the results of a method are correct based on different values of a static variable.

Here is a simple example:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
     Object1.StaticMember = 1
     Object2 test = new Object2();
     Assert.AreEqual("1", test.getStaticVal());
}

public void TestMethod2()
{
     Object1.StaticMember = 2
     Object2 test = new Object2();
     Assert.AreEqual("2", test.getStaticVal());
}
```

I was informed that unit tests in VS2012 are excecuted concurrently so there is a posibility of the tests failing. Is this true? How can I write the tests to run one at a time?

Comment: possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632975/static-class-method-property-in-unit-test-stop-it-or-not.

Comment: Really so is that means these two test repeatedly pass in VS2010? Is there  more reference detail I can read about the VS2012 concurrency tests running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way to do it but you can always use a lock object like this...

```
    private static Object LockObject = new object();

    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        lock(LockObject)
        {
            Object1.StaticMember = 1;
            Object2 test = new Object2();
            Assert.AreEqual("1", test.getStaticVal());
        }
    }

    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {
            Object1.StaticMember = 2;
            Object2 test = new Object2();
            Assert.AreEqual("2", test.getStaticVal());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I hear you... sometimes you inherit things that are quite difficult to test.